# mypy not taking previously performed typecheck into account when evaluating types for arithmetic computation

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a python class that looks as following:

```
from typing import Optional, Union, Dict
import numpy as np

class TestClass():

    def __init__(self, a: Optional[float] = None, b: Optional[float] = None):
        self.a = 1 if a is None else a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def input_values(self) -> Dict[str, Union[float, None]]:
        return {'a': self.a, 'b': self.b}

    @property
    def test_property(self) -> float:
        if None in self.input_values.values():
            raise KeyError('missing values')

        return self.a+self.b
```

evaluating it with mypy returns the error statement

```
error: Unsupported operand types for + ("float" and "None")
note: Right operand is of type "Optional[float]"
```

But I am making sure both values cannot be None at this point of the control flow. Is there a different way that is recognized by mypy by which I can perfom these typechecks?

Comment: You have to see that mypy does not do runtime analysis.  So it does not learn anything from the test `if None in self.input_values.values()` as it would require to actually execute method `input_values`.  For mypy, in your return statement, `self.b` has type `Optional[float]` (because of its initialisation in the `__init__` method). And that's it.

Comment: @qouify but if I set the input type for a value that is later used for arithmetic to Optional[float] mypy raises an error. Can I still keep this functionality and still use mypy?

Comment: If you really need `b` to be an `Optional[float]` and not force it to be a `float` as you've done with `a` you can use a `cast` whenever you are sure that `b` cannot contain `None` for sure, like this: `typing.cast(float, self.b)`.  mypy can exploit this information in its type checks.

Comment: (Btw, you should perhaps delete your previous post that seems like a draft of this one.)

Comment: Is there any reason why you go the route of constructing an auxiliary ``dict`` for the checking? A simple ``if self.b is None:`` should have been enough.

Answer (score 0):

Narrowing of types is very limited in mypy, one of method permitted is assert, this is working in mypy:

```
def test_property(self) -> float:
    if None in self.input_values.values():
        raise KeyError('missing values')
    assert isinstance(self.a, float) and isinstance(self.b, float)
    return self.a + self.b
```